# AppleScript to move specific iCal events on by one week

Tags: events, date, applescript, move, icalendar

I have iCal events scheduled for various clients over a 6 week period based on a certain start date. ie Client 1,2 and 3 start on the next Monday and I have several iCal events set over a 6 week period that will trigger other different AppleScripts etc. (That works fine, but...)

If Client 2 decides to go on the program 1 week later than 1 and 3 and I have already scheduled his events, how do I select the already created events in iCal for Client 2 and move them all up by one week?

Here's what I've got thus far:

```
tell application "Calendar"
tell calendar "ExampleCalendar"
set theEventList to every event whose summary contains "Client2"
end tell
end tell
```

This will select the events, now how do I move them all up one week (they all have different start dates obviously and are unequally spaced apart)

This would make my life much easier! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Yosemite users can now [reference selected Calendar events in AppleScript](https://www.johneday.com/1086/reference-selected-calendar-events-applescript)

Try:

```
set daysAdded to 7

tell application "iCal"
    tell calendar "ExampleCalendar"
        set theEventList to every event whose summary contains "Client2"
        repeat with anEvent in theEventList
            tell anEvent
                set it's end date to (it's end date) + daysAdded * days
                set it's start date to (it's start date) + daysAdded * days
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Here is an alternate method.

```
        tell anEvent
            set {sDate, eDate} to {(it's start date), (it's end date)}
            set it's start date to sDate + daysAdded * days
            set it's end date to eDate + daysAdded * days
        end tell
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked (for the most part). Here's what happens: 
The events' start dates were moved 7 days, but then their new end dates were 7 days from the new start date. ie the events were now 7 days long.
If I remove the line:
`set it's end date to (it's end date) + daysAdded * days`
then, the events gets moved on, but the new end dates are now the same as the new start dates.

Comment: Do you need to set the end date manually? "set start date to start date + daysAdded * days" should do the job

Comment: @user1812282. Good point. Changing the order of the commands should fix the problem. See my edited version.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I finally got around to it and your suggestion worked. I swapped the order around and it works perfectly. Thank you!